# Windows 7 and 8.0 bug: Store: PC is not connected to Internet, try again later

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

The Windows 8 Store application on my computer claims that my computer is not connected to the internet.

My computer IS actually connected to the internet, but for some reason the store application can't seem to tell that my internet is working. I Know that the connection is not bad because I can browse the internet as per usual.

Why is the store seemingly unable to use my computer's operable internet connection?

The computer that i'm having this problem on is a Dell Inspiron 7720 laptop. It is new and came pre-loaded with this operating system (Windows 8)

I Tried deleting and recreating the main user account on my computer, as well as disabling the firewall, but neither attempts fixed my problem.

**UPDATE**

I found, that the same situation is on my big computer. I just not thinking to use Store, so didn't noticed it. So, the suspect is my router configuration. It is D-Link DIR-615

I am using local accounts.

DNS client service is running

**UPDATE 2**

Switching to MS user account didn't help.

**UPDATE 3**

In Microsoft Community guys said this problem is related with another one I have [Windows 7 and 8.0 bug: Network icon is marked as "no internet access"](https://superuser.com/questions/677608/network-icon-is-marked-as-no-internet-access)

Nobody knows why is this happen too.

Also I noticed, that sometimes some computer icons in LAN suddenly feel that they are in Internet, and at that time Store start to work.

When this happened, I have installed Windows upgrade to 8.1 and the problem disappears. So This is Windows 7 and 8.0 bug.

Comment: Do you sign in with a local account or a microsoft account?

Comment: @Dims - Windows 7 doesn't have a `Windows Store` application.  How can it be a Windows 7 bug if the application does not even exist on Windows 7?

Comment: @Ramhound question has a link to Windows 7 equivalent: http://superuser.com/questions/677608/windows-7-and-8-0-bug-network-icon-is-marked-as-no-internet-access

Comment: @Dims - Does not change the fact.  The question is about a Windows 8 machine and the Windows Store application which does not exist and cannot be ran on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

The steps a windows machine uses to discover internet access are here:

[How does Windows know whether it has internet access or if a Wi-Fi connection requires in-browser authentication?](https://superuser.com/questions/277923/how-does-windows-know-whether-it-has-internet-access-or-if-a-wi-fi-connection-re)

Try doing those manually and see where you get stuck. In particular check that none of the magic URLs are blocked by a firewall or have erroneous entries in your hosts or hostslm file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it happened when the DNS Client service is stopped. Run `services.msc` and make sure the DNS service is running.

Comment: DNS client service does running at mine computer

Answer (score -1):

Same thing happened to me on a few Lenovo ThinkPad T430. Couldn't access the Windows Store to upgrade to 8.1.

Checking the description on [this](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/16/windows-7-network-awareness/) article, I checked the DNS resolution and detected no problem there. I could also access *http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt* from a browser with no trouble.

Looking further, I noticed the following registry key was set to 0 instead of the default 1. Changing it to 1 solved the problem.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters\Internet\EnableActiveProbing