# Windows 7 and 8.0 bug: Network icon is marked as "no internet access"

Tags: windows-8, internet, troubleshooting

When does windows mark network connection icon as having no internet access?

I have internet access, but the icon says I don't. If I run troubleshooter, it finds no any problems. But the icon still says no internet access (yellow triangle with exclamation mark).

**UPDATE**

Problem manifestates on several computers in the LAN, so it is not network card dependent.

Also problem is related with Windows Store operation: [Windows 7 and 8.0 bug: Store: PC is not connected to Internet, try again later](https://superuser.com/questions/675606/windows-7-and-8-0-bug-store-pc-is-not-connected-to-internet-try-again-later)

Also problem disappears on Windows 8.1, so this is a bug of Windows 8.0

[image]

Comment: can you access this file in a browser? http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt . this is how windows determines whether it is online or not. see this thread for more details: http://superuser.com/questions/277923/how-does-windows-know-whether-it-has-internet-access-or-if-a-wi-fi-connection-re

Comment: Yes, I can access `ncsi.txt` with browser. This is normal file on a web server. Why would I can't access it? I said, the Internet is functionning, only Store subsystem is not. Of course Store subsystem determines internet some other way, because if it check this file, it would report Internet is ok, as it is. Looking at your SU link...

Comment: there are a wide variety of reasons you might not be able to reach the file, but if your devices are saying they don't have internet access, they are not retrieving it as expected.

Comment: Only parts of devices say that there is no access: network icon and windows store. No any other software say, including browsers. This is the problem.

Comment: Do you actually *have* Internet access? If you just have access to the world wide web, you don't have Internet access, you have Web access. Do non-web Internet applications work? (If you can't access the web without a proxy, then you probably don't have Internet access. That's why you need a proxy.)

Answer (score 5):

Try the following :
Go to Computer -> System properties -> Device Manager --> Network adapters: double-click this entry in the list

- Now Right-click your network adapter (or wireless adapter) --> Uninstall … **BUT LEAVE "UNCHECKED"** the box marked “Delete the driver software for this device”
- After uninstalling, the Device Manager list refreshes. In the blue area near the top of the screen, click Actions, then Scan for hardware changes.This should reinstall the network adapter, and the device driver software for it.
- Restart your PC.

Comment: I don't see checkbox to control software deletion... When should it appear?

Comment: After you Click "Uninstall" , you should be asked if you want to uninstall this device, you click Yes.Then you should see the Box "Delete the driver software for this device" , In case you don't see it just continue the steps.

Comment: I think this happens when we access internet using proxy server.

Comment: You will only see the checkbox for driver software deletion if you installed the drivers separately after the Operating System installation.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Windows 10), it seemed to be an invalid local certificate created by an old installment (maybe created by Fiddler?) which I had on Windows 8 before I upgraded to Windows 10.

Go to:

1. Control Panel -> Internet Options -> Content -> Certificates ->
   Personal
2. Check if you have a certificate with status invalid
3. Remove it.
4. Reboot.

Answer (score -1):

If there is a "plane mode" under your Windows device, you can use it (turn it on and then off) to refresh this icon without rebooting. It works fine under my Windows 7 laptop.

Of course, you will have to repeat this every time you face the problem but it is a quick and easy way to proceed.