# How windows detects internet connection?

Tags: windows-7, internet-connection

I have a Huwaei data card and **Aircel SIM**. I don't have internet plan or balance in my prepaid SIM but whenever I connect Internet it gets connected and windows shows **Internet access**.

and in fact I don't have internet access it just shows Internet access.

[image]

My question is how windows detects Internet connection ?

Comment: See the answers at http://superuser.com/questions/277923/how-does-windows-know-whether-it-has-internet-access-or-if-a-wi-fi-connection-re and [this SU blog post](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/16/windows-7-network-awareness/).

Answer (score 0):

It shows "Internet Access" whenever a ping request returns a success for pinging "www.windows.com". This means that if your system is set up to redirect you to a payment page or something of that sort, it is going to return a ping from there too, tricking the computer that it is connected to the internet.

Source: Schools WiFi and Wireshark