# Why would Windows Machines Display no internet when there is an internet connection?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, internet-connection

See the image to understand what I mean. The machine displays no internet on the wifi id display(see image) but there is a connection that still exists. I've been witnessing the same behavior on pretty much at least 30 Win 10 machines so far.

[image]

Comment: Delete (forget) the connection and remake it. That will normally solve the issue (and does for me.)

Comment: that is a good temporary solution. I need something more concrete and permanent.

Comment: start here to understand how windows makes the determination that its connected or not: https://superuser.com/questions/277923/how-does-windows-know-whether-it-has-internet-access-or-if-a-wi-fi-connection-re

Comment: Delete your wireless profiles (netsh wlan delete profile name="profile name" for all wireless profiles. Restart, remake your main wireless profile and that should be permanent.

Comment: What is in common with these 30 machines

Comment: looks like it is relative to this but am still investigating.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-says-i-have-no-internet-connection-but/50153e5b-a008-443d-af0e-5ee3822c37a1?auth=1&page=9

Comment: @Ramhound Windows 10 OS 1903 build and higher and it doesnt happen in other OS's or smartphones

Comment: Yes; Clear out your wireless profiles.  The same access point appears to be listed multiple times.

Comment: "The same access point appears to be listed multiple times" - False and look again

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that NCSI reports no internet. NCSI primarily gets it work done through the use of network probes - a simple network request to an endpoint followed by a response. There are many different types of probes including active, passive, corporate, proxy, default gateway, and others. In addition some probes are done via HTTP, DNS, or both.

If NCSI sends the probe and receives a valid response it considers the client machine internet-connected.

You could try modify the following registry key to see if the issue can be resolved.

[Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\NetworkConnectivityStatusIndicator] **NoActiveProbe** set to 0 (should either not present or value must be 0)

Restart the machine and see if NCSI still reports no internet.